# Reportportal to JIRA integration fails with error: Impossible interact with external system

Tags: jira, reportportal

I am trying to integrate a project in Reportportal to JIRA project. When trying to configure, it is failing with error "Impossible interact with external system" like the attached picture.

The Jira service is up in docker. The https cert on JIRA is valid CA signed cert (i.e. Not self signed). I ruled out importing cert into jira service container.
The JIRA instance uses NTLM for authentication. I am not sure if Basic auth that reportportal jira service is trying working here.

Thanks for hep.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into `service-jira` docker container logs. This will give details what's happening during this response.

and you also can drop as a mail to `support@reportportal.io`

Answer (score 0):

Try This out !
You should take care of following points for reportportal.io integration with jira.

`Link to BTS`: This link should be correct.[**https://jira.company.com**]
`Project name in Jira`: Use project key instead of name. project key should taken from jira.
`BTS username`: Use jira email here.
`BTS password`: Use jira API token instead of password for Jira-cloud [Go to Jira account setting and generate new token or search how to generate jira API token]

All the best !